# javascriptexecutor not working with angularjs forms

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a login form by selenium webdriver (javascriptexucutor) which is built in angularjs. The script is entering data in email textbox; but when submit button is clicked error message shows that textbox is not filled. I have also used events like onkeyup, blur; but error shows these functions are not accepted. Textbox validaton works fine with sendkeys() and it takes time; but facing issue when javascriptexecutor is used.
html code:

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="logindata($event)" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email ID" value="" name="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="email">`
```

selenium-java code:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='tester'", emailElement);
```

Comment: It is working in Chrome and Firefox what is the issue

Comment: It is entering value in textbox; but when Submit button is click; I m getting alert popup: The email id field is blank. Means its not locating the value.

Comment: Please share complete detail to me. Why you are not use sendkeys

Comment: sendKeys() works fine; but it takes time for large forms. So I was expecting to use javascript to validate test. One more thing; when I use same javascript syntax on normal html forms; I used onkeyup() and it worked. But in angularJS forms, its not locating the value.

Comment: Still I suggest you have to use the sendkeys() and your question how to send text using javascript which is supposed to work. For your issue I need some more Details

Comment: e.g. this website is built in angularJS. Please try to input any data and submit using javascript. http://oditek.in/ikomplianzWeb/client/

Comment: Yes this is the issue

Comment: It seems the issue , We can send value to the form when page is not loaded thats why it does not  recognize it

Comment: The main cause is angularJS forms. Some said that Protractor framework will work. So plz inform if you have any other alternatives. Thanks

Comment: Yes @girija I will

Comment: @GirijaMallick: does it work wen you place large amount of delay before interacting with the element?

Comment: Yes i have added explicit wait. Still the same issue occurred. And it doesn't locate the textbox value.

Comment: I have used Protractor framework also. Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me but you Try this alternative way

```
JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
myExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('email"')[0].value='Tester'");
```